# Text widget data does not become centered

Tags: text, flutter, dart

I have a text widget (in a container). The text within the widget always appears left-aligned.

```
 Container(decoration: myBoxDecoration(),
                     child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                       Center(child: Text('Historical Information Below (latest Results at top)', textAlign: TextAlign.center,))],),
                   ),
```

I've used the parameter:

```
TextAlign: TextAlign.center
```

but alas, this is of no avail.

I've even added this Text widget in a Center widget, and that has done nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have `Text` widget inside `Row` widget.

So, add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` to `Row`

```
Container(
  decoration: myBoxDecoration(),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Text(
          'Historical Information Below (latest Results at top)',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

or remove `Row`

```
Container(
  decoration: myBoxDecoration(),
  child: Center(
    child: Text(
      'Historical Information Below (latest Results at top)',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
  ),
)
```